# Modify struct field inside of Option

Tags: rust

I'm having problems in changing a field of a struct inside of option. This is the code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    field1 : i32,
    field2 : i32,
    // and many more...
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn field1(&mut self, field1 : i32) -> &mut Self {
        self.field1 = field1;
        self
    }
}

fn foo() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    None
}

fn bar() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    foo().as_mut().map(|s| s.field1(5))
}

fn main() {
    bar();
}
```

The main idea of `bar()` is to get an `Option<MyStruct>` from another function returning an `Option<MyStruct>`, change a field of that struct (in case the result is not `None`) and return the resulting `Option<MyStruct>`.

The struct implements the builder pattern, so I've used it.

In this case I get the following error:

```
test.rs:18:5: 18:40 error: mismatched types:
expected `core::option::Option<MyStruct>`,
    found `core::option::Option<&mut MyStruct>`
(expected struct `MyStruct`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
test.rs:18     foo().as_mut().map(|s| s.field1(5))
```

I've also tried to use `Option.take()` and to change the signature of the builder method as `pub fn field1(mut self, field1 : i32) -> Self`, but none of them work.

How can I make this code work?

I know that I could create another `Option` and map every field of the input to the corresponding field of the output, but `MyStruct` has a lot of fields and it is tedious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no reason to use `as_mut()` at all. Because you need to return `MyStruct` by value, you can just `map` on the option:

```
fn bar() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    foo().map(|mut s| { s.field1(5); s })
}
```

That's it. You need to mark `s` with `mut` for the same reason you need to do so with `let`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It keeps saying the same error as before: mismatched types. Maybe it is the signature of `field1()`?

Comment: You need `|mut s| { s.field1(5); s }`. The method modifies the object but its return value, the &mut, is useless for returning by-value.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right. I don't know why I used builder-like syntax. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev ok, now it's working and it's a minimal change. Solved for me.

Answer (score 9):

TBH, I would just do it the obvious way:

```
fn bar() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    let mut val = foo();
    if let Some(ref mut s) = val {
        s.field1(5);
    }
    val
}
```

It is longer than using `map`, but I find using `map` to mutate to be uncomfortable and the explicit mutation I choose also produces much nicer assembly.

Comment: Yes, this is clear and effective, however I wanted to know why `map` didn't work in the way I've used it.

Answer (score 3):

Since other people are chiming in with broader suggestions, I'd point out that you can change your "builder" syntax to use `self` by value. For an actual builder, this is usually more ergonomic:

```
struct MyStruct {
    field1: i32,
    field2: i32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn field1(self, field1: i32) -> Self {
        MyStruct { field1: field1, ..self }
    }
}

fn foo() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    None
}

fn bar() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    foo().map(|s| s.field1(5))
}

fn main() {
    bar();
}
```

I also tend to make a distinction between *builders* and plain *chained method invocation*. Namely, a builder should have a `build` method (or equivalent) that actually returns a different type. A builder is often a short-lived type, and so passing by value rarely causes problems.

Comment: I don't know if it's always as you said. I saw examples where the builder is the result itself and its methods take `self` by `&mut`. But maybe it's clearer to use a different struct for the construction like you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *Check Vladimir's answer, it's better.*

Let's remove the chaining, should we?

```
fn bar() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    let x: Option<MyStruct> = foo();
    let x: Option<&mut MyStruct> = x.as_mut();
    let x: Option<&mut MyStruct> = x.map(|s| s.field1(5));
    x
}
```

So, with the fluff removed, the question is:

> How can I transform a `Option<&mut MyStruct>` into a `Option<MyStruct>`?

You cannot as-is, the borrowing rules forbid taking ownership of something you only borrow.

You have two alternatives:

- make a clone
- go back to the owner

Let's illustrate them:

```
// Requires that MyStruct implement Clone,
// use #[derive(Clone)] to auto-generate the implementation
fn bar_copy() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    foo().as_mut().map(|s| s.field1(5).clone())
}

fn bar_back() -> Option<MyStruct> {
    let mut my_struct = foo();
    my_struct.as_mut().map(|s| s.field1(5));
    my_struct
}
```

Pick whichever you prefer (I'd pick the latter to avoid copies).

Comment: BTW, in your second example I'd say it is more idiomatic to use `if let`: `if let Some(ref mut s) = my_struct { s.field1(5); }`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: I was going with minimal modifications to the OP code (as the example might be contrived), but removing the `as_mut` as you did is just plain better.

Comment: Good explanation. I've tried the second version and it works for me. However Vladimir answer does this in one line.

Comment: @brt: Yep, that's why I added a disclaimer at the top of my answer; Vladimir's answer is just plain better :)